# Why is Solr's qf field causing some documents not to match at all?

Tags: solr

I am searching Solr with a querystring of:

`q=now+I+can+see+this`

The text I am searching for, "now I can see this", **does** exist in an indexed document, in the `field1` field. Yet when I perform the search described above, zero documents are returned.

In my solrconfig.xml, I have defined these defaults:

```
<str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
<str name="q.op">AND</str>
<str name="defType">edismax</str>

<str name="qf">
    field1 field2^2 field3^2 field4
</str>

<str name="pf">
    field1 
</str>
```

The only way I can get the document to be returned is to change qf to:

```
<str name="qf">
    field1
</str>
```

In other words, to drop field2, field3, field4 boosts. My understanding is that `qf` provides a boost to the score, but doesn't otherwise impact the search that is happening, so I don't understand why dropping the additional fields results in me being able to find the document with the given query.

When I put debugQuery=true on the querystring, this is what I am seeing for the parsedquery, but nothing is jumping out at me (admittedly I'm still new to debugging queries in Solr).

`(+((DisjunctionMaxQuery((field4:now | field1:now | field3:now^2.0 | field2:now^2.0)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((field4:i | field1:i | field3:i^2.0 | field2:i^2.0)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((field4:can | field1:can | field3:can^2.0 | field2:can^2.0)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((field4:see | field1:see | field3:see^2.0 | field2:see^2.0)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((field4:this | field3:this^2.0 | field2:this^2.0)))~5) DisjunctionMaxQuery((field1:\"now i can see\")))/no_coord`

Here's parsedquery_tostring:

`+(((field4:now | field1:now | field3:now^2.0 | field2:now^2.0) (field4:i | field1:i | field3:i^2.0 | field2:i^2.0) (field4:can | field1:can | field3:can^2.0 | field2:can^2.0) (field4:see | field1:see | field3:see^2.0 | field2:see^2.0) (field4:this | field3:this^2.0 | field2:this^2.0))~5) (field1:\"now i can see\")`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you have *"this"* in field1? Is it the same when you are using :

```
<str name="qf">
    field1
</str>
```

Are you using SpellCheck or FuzzySearch features?

**Edit :**

If you are using stopWords only for field1, this is what happens :

When you are using :

```
<str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
<str name="q.op">AND</str>
<str name="defType">edismax</str>

<str name="qf">
    field1 field2^2 field3^2 field4
</str>
```

You want each term of your query to appear at least once in either field (field1, field2, field3 and field4).

For the first 4 terms, you have what you want, each term appears in one field (field1).

For *this*, you are using a stopWord that you will delete when you querying on field1. So you are not searching *this* in field1 but you are looking for this term into field2, field3 and field4. But *this* doesn't appear in these fields. Finally, you can not find all the terms of your query and you are using an AND operator, so 0 documents are returned.

When you are using :

```
<str name="qf">
    field1
</str>
```

You are not looking for the term *this* because in all yours fields using to search, this term is delete due to the stopWords file. So you will find all your terms of the query and you will have expected results.

I hope I was clear and helpful.

Comment: Yep, it's the same. I think it's because "this" is a stop word defined in the indexer and query analyzers. I do not have spellcheck or fuzzysearch turned on.

Comment: So, if you are using <str name="q.op">AND</str>, you dont't want having documents when you are looking for this sentence?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking?

Comment: I think that if you are using an AND opérator, in theorie, you will not have results if you don't have a term that you queryied on. Use [link]http://explain.solr.pl to see how score is calculated when you are just using field1 !

Comment: That seems weird in this case because the stop words processing is being done on both index and query, but I'll check into it. The other thing that seems to disprove it is if I only have field1 in the qf field, I do see the document again. It doesn't make sense that if I just add additional boost fields, the document gets dropped?

Comment: BTW, thanks for that link to explain.solr.pl, I hadn't seen that before!

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make sense, are you using the same filedType for each field?

Comment: No, for field1 I'm using a custom field definition that has a lot of processing (including the stop word processing), and for the other fields I'm using text_general).

Comment: Can you add snippets of schema.xml for field1?

Comment: OK so with your fields 2 to 4, you are not using stopWords? I edit my first post.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely helpful. :) However, I guess I'm still confused as to why the `qf` field is limiting my search at all. I was under the impression `qf` was designed to let you assign boosts IF the keyword is found in the boosted field. I didn't realize it would require the keyword to be found. Is there a way to boost IF FOUND in a field, but not REQUIRE a match in that field?

Comment: You can use the [boost query parameter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebq(BoostQuery)Parameter)

Comment: `qf` will only specify fields that you want query on (with optionnal boost) !